# ImageMagick to compare 2 images, marked with 2 different color on the output image

Tags: image, imagemagick, comparison, difference

I want make 2 different colors on the output image when using Imagemagick. I have an original image with "Hello World" in it. And a modified image with "Hello Warcraft" in the same area. The default compare command will give me a image and mark all the differences with red.

Now I want to use 2 different colors like "orld" marked as red, and "arcraft" marked as another color, maybe blue. Is ImageMagick able to do this?

If not, how to use ImageMagick to transfer a specified color to another one?

Below are the sample.

[Image A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc1kq.png)

[Image B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SwRy.png)

Then I use the compare like: compare imageA.png imageB.png imageC.png

then the Image C will be:

[Image C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRVIY.png)

But now I just know there are some differences between Image A and Image B. so I want to make some color-code on the Image C, it could be like below Image D:

[Image D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txtnD.png)

from this I can know which parts are the same, and Green means what the difference on Image A and Red means what's the difference on Image B.

Comment: I do not understand the question. Can you post some example images to a free hosting service and put the URLs here? Then explain a bit better what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have free server. I will try to explain it like this: Image A show a car, Image B show a bike, if compare them, both car and bike will be marked as red color on image C. right? now I want to do some color-marked. the car is blue and bike is red. so I can get infomation from image C that how differences between A and B.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in ImageMagick 6 (Unix Syntax).

ImageA:

[image]

ImageB:

[image]

```
convert img1.png img2b.png \
-define compose:args="0,1,-1,0.5" \
-compose mathematics -composite -auto-level \
\( xc:red xc:blue +append \) -clut diff.png
```

[image]

This is a biased difference. Anything above 0.5 or mid gray (in normalized values) will be one color corresponding to one image and anything below 0.5 will be the other color corresponding to the other image.

See [clut](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#clut) and [compose mathematics](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#mathematics)

For ImageMagick 7, change convert to magick.

**ADDITION:**

Given your new input images. Here is how to do that:

imageA:

[image]

imageB:

[image]

```
convert imageA.png imageB.png -write mpr:img +delete -fill white -colorize 80% \
\( mpr:img -compose minus -composite -threshold 0 -background red -alpha shape \) \
\( mpr:img +swap -compose minus -composite -threshold 0 -background blue -alpha shape \) \
-background none -compose over -flatten result.png
```

[image]

Sorry, I used blue in stead of green. But you can change that if you want.

Comment: thanks very much. But there is a problem for my idea. The backgroud color changed, and cannot see the same part, which is "Hello W". I still want to keep the same part on the result image. if you use compare command, it will give you a difference result image, and I just want to mark the difference places with different color, default is all RED. I modified the question and add some images to explam the result. could you please help to check that? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, but compare does not have the ability to color the way you want. But see my ADDITION to my answer.

Comment: Many thanks. That's great and also can consider as the "compare" result. it really helps me a lot. Thanks for your help. Can I ask one last question? if I want to use this command in the java program, where I already import im4Java, now try to build the command in the program
        IMOperation cmpOp = new IMOperation();
        cmpOp.addImage(expected);
        cmpOp.addImage(actual);
        cmpOp.write("mpr:img");
        cmpOp.p_delete();
        cmpOp.fill("white");
        cmpOp.colorize(80);
for the "\\(" and "\\)" in the command, do you know how to build it?

Comment: Please ignore my last question in the comment, I find out the way by checking the im4java packaged code. use cmpOp.addSuboption(). thank you. 